# filtering a list of table rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery

This list isn't being filter, I get the same length before and after the filter is executed. The `txt` and `val` values are correct.

```
$("#filter").on('keyup', function(e){
  var val = this.value.toLowerCase();

  c.log('trs', $trs.length);
  $trs.filter(function(i){
    var $el = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2) a')
      , txt = $el.text().toLowerCase();

    //c.log('test', txt, val);
    return !!txt.indexOf(val);
  });

  c.log('trs', $trs.length);
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="numeric"><a id="btc" class="rank">1</a></td>
    <td>
        <img src="img/Bitcoin.png" class="currency-logo">
        <a href="http://www.bitcoin.org" target="_blank">Bitcoin</a>
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="numeric"><a id="ltc" class="rank">2</a></td>
    <td>
         <img src="img/Litecoin.png" class="currency-logo">
         <a href="http://litecoin.org" target="_blank">Litecoin</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: in td use .html() not .val(). try alert(val) // i don`t think it will retun any data ..

Comment: please post relevant html and give some more explanations.

Comment: i'm not using `.val()`. I posted the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just assumed that `filter` will do modifications on the source object. But it is not. It actually returns a set of `filtered elements` based on the condition provided inside it. Please read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Try this,

```
$("#filter").on('keyup', function(e){

     var val = this.value.toLowerCase();    
     c.log('trs', $trs.length);

     c.log('trs',   $trs.filter(function(i){
       var $el = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2) a');
       var txt = $el.text().toLowerCase();
       return txt.indexOf(val) > -1;
     }).length;
   );

});
```

Comment: That was it I had to re-assign it.